# How to set different width of elements [iPhone-dev]

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uilabel

Look this pic:

[image]

The usernames are UIButton. How can I put a UILabel (with the comment text) just after the UIButton (with the username) ?

The UIButton username's is dynamic. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a `UITableView`, if that's the case you should subclass `UITableViewCell`. If it isn't, I would

1. consider making it one
2. build a container class that (or make your subclassed `UITableViewCell` such that it) contains both a UIButton and a UILabel and dynamically position the text inside the label according to the size of the button (for instance, adding the right number of spaces to the beginning of the text).

Comment: This really wouldn't work, because the label would have to wrap to multiple lines in a non-rectangular fashion. That is, the label would have to start just to the right of the button but flow underneath the button on the next line(s).

Comment: sure it would. append the appropriate number of spaces to the beginning of the text in the label. positioning the label wouldn't work though, you're right. i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use Core Text or web views to achieve this. There's really not a super easy way to do this. It's simple enough to place view next to each other based on their calculated sizes, but to have text wrap to multiple lines with embedded font style variations and attachments (i.e., images), you're going to have to read up on Core Text or use XHTML in web views.

Comment: Just check the documentation for Core Text. There are more than enough examples and sample code. Same with Google. :)